# Mismatch between associated type and type parameter only when impl is marked `default`

Tags: rust, traits

The following code results in an error ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3338a33b7629fa3f2a9f001a492b6c55&version=nightly&mode=debug))

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait Foo {
    type Assoc;
    fn foo(&self) -> &Self::Assoc;
}

default impl<T> Foo for T {
    type Assoc = T;
    fn foo(&self) -> &Self::Assoc {
        self
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:9
   |
20 |         self
   |         ^^^^ expected associated type, found type parameter
   |
   = note: expected type `&<T as Foo>::Assoc`
              found type `&T`
```

This is strange since `<T as Foo>::Assoc` *is* `T`, so it should work. Stranger even: when I remove the `default` keyword from the impl, it works (but of course, in my real code, I need to mark the impl as `default`).

The same error happens when providing default values in the trait definition ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=003c73d79ba0165c7b9aa6a74e5b7e57&version=nightly&mode=debug)):

```
#![feature(specialization)]
#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]

trait Foo {
    type Assoc = Self;
    fn foo(&self) -> &Self::Assoc {
        self
    }
}
```

---

What's going on here? Is this a compiler bug? Or -- and that's why I'm asking this question -- does this error make sense because there is something special about specialization that I haven't understood yet? In case this is a bug, `mem::transmute` is surely safe, riiiight?

Comment: The first example runs in the playground. The second one *should* fail, since you could write `impl Foo for String { type Assoc = i32; }`

Comment: @trentcl I'm sorry, the first playground link was wrong :( I just fixed it. Now it has the same code as in my question and doesn't compile. Good point about the second example!

Comment: In the ['default impl' tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37653) it says: "all items in a default impl are (implicitly) default and hence specializable" I guess, this means marking an impl as default also turns associated types into specializable default types - regardless of whether the `associated_type_defaults` feature is enabled. In this case it makes sense that the first example should fail for the same reason as the second example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Specialization` feature is showing no signs of stabilising, mostly because of [soundness concerns](http://aturon.github.io/blog/2017/07/08/lifetime-dispatch/), so you should expect some problems.

You have this:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait Foo {
    type Assoc;
    fn foo(&self) -> &Self::Assoc;
}

default impl<T> Foo for T {
    type Assoc = T;
    fn foo(&self) -> &Self::Assoc {
        self
    }
}
```

But imagine that you added another implementation with its own associated type but without implementing `foo`. This implementation's `foo` will be "inherited" from the other, less specific, implementation:

```
impl<T: SomeConstraint> Foo for T {
    type Assoc = NotT;
}
```

Then there'd be a problem. Your `foo` would be returning a `T` but, whenever T is `SomeConstraint` there'd be a type mismatch because it should be returning a `NotT`.

[RFC 2532 — associated type defaults](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2532-associated-type-defaults.html) mentions a possible solution in its [Future Work section](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2532-associated-type-defaults.html#future-possibilities). A hypothetical `default` block could be used to indicate that associated type(s) and method(s) would need to be specialized together. There's no sign of when such a feature would be considered for inclusion, however.

Comment: Oh snap, that's possible? I would have assumed that the compiler would complain about the second impl. Mh so I guess the feature is even less stable than I thought... Thanks!