# Implement something similar to C++'s `std::remove_reference` in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'd like to have a tool to remove the reference from a type if the type is a reference. Something like this (pseudo code):

```
remove_ref(i32)      == i32
remove_ref(&i32)     == i32
remove_ref(&&i32)    == i32
remove_ref(&mut i32) == i32
```

C++ has [`std::remove_reference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_reference/) in the standard library which can do exactly what I want. I tried to implement the same in Rust, but I can't get it working. Right now, the only way to "output" types in Rust are associated types on traits (I think). I tried something like this ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1d77c235aaefd325612ff742029bbc3b&version=nightly&mode=debug)):

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait RemoveRef {
    type WithoutRef;
}

default impl<T> RemoveRef for T {
    type WithoutRef = T;
}

impl<'a, T: RemoveRef> RemoveRef for &'a T {
    type WithoutRef = T::WithoutRef;
}
```

And in fact this compiles. Promising! (yes, this doesn't account for mutable references yet). However, everything explodes when I try to use it:

```
let _: <i32 as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
let _: <&i32 as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
let _: <&&i32 as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
```

The first line leads to "overflow evaluating the requirement `i32: RemoveRef`". The other two lines produce the error "the trait bound `&i32: RemoveRef` is not satisfied". I'm not sure if I just don't understand this or if specialization is broken. (Related: I got another strange error with very similar code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022636/mismatch-between-associated-type-and-type-parameter-only-when-impl-is-marked-de))

I was thinking about other possibilities to implement this: maybe put a type parameter on the trait? Maybe GATs could help here? Are there other features in the language that allow mapping from one type to another type?

**Is there any way to implement something like this in Rust?**

Comment: Should this be restricted to `Copy` types like `i32`? In this case a `remove_ref` function could look like this: `fn remove_ref<T: Copy>(t : &T) -> T{*t}` example usage: `let i = remove_ref::<i32>(&mut &&mut 42);`

Comment: @Calculator Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, that's not quite what I meant. I see now that my pseudo code in the beginning is kind of confusing. A Rust function maps from value to value. I want something that maps from type to type (which I think can only be done with traits). My whole question doesn't care about actual values.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple approach that works without the specialization feature:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait RemoveRef {
    type WithoutRef;
}

struct Ref<T> {
    phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> RemoveRef for Ref<T> {
    type WithoutRef = T;
}

impl<'a, T: RemoveRef> RemoveRef for &'a T {
    type WithoutRef = T::WithoutRef;
}

fn main() {
    let _: <Ref<i32> as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
    let _: <&Ref<i32> as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
    let _: <&&&&Ref<i32> as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
}
```

Not sure though if it can be made compatible with your actual use case in this form or if it is useful at all.

Alternatively, it is of course also possible to replace your generic exit condition (`impl<T> RemoveRef for T`) with implementations for concrete types:

```
impl RemoveRef for i32 {
    type WithoutRef = Self;
}
```

This enables your original test code:

```
let _: <i32 as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
let _: <&i32 as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
let _: <&&i32 as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
```

---

AFAIK specializations cannot help you to fix overlapping issue like the one between `for T` and `for &'a T` at this point. It would require features like negative trait bounds.

All items in a `default impl` are implicitly default. If you move the `default` keyword to the associated type in your code you get rid of the evaluation overflow, but you get other errors:

```
impl<T> RemoveRef for T {
    default type WithoutRef = T;
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:45
   |
16 |     let _: <i32 as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef = 3;
   |                                             ^ expected associated type, found integral variable
   |
   = note: expected type `<i32 as RemoveRef>::WithoutRef`
              found type `{integer}`
```

This fails for the same reason as discussed here: [Mismatch between associated type and type parameter only when impl is marked `default`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51026699/7274990) Assigning `T` to `WithoutRef` in combination with `default` does not constrain `WithoutRef` to type `T`.

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting, didn't think of that solution. Sadly, the `Ref<_>` implementation does in fact not help in my actual use case. Sad that this probably won't work with specialization :/

Comment: I think this problem could actually be solved by [RFC 2532](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2532). When this get merged, I will revisit this question.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Link says it is merged now

Comment: @NooneAtAll Unfortunately (at least for this question), the scope of the RFC was scaled back a lot. So I don't think it changes anything regarding this question anymore.