# How can I write a method to wrap any value in my type that can be called multiple times without requiring type annotations?

Tags: rust

I wrote a type `Wrapper<T>` which contains a value of `T`:

```rust
struct Wrapper<T>(T);
```

I want a method `to_wrap` which would allow me to write code like this, where `b` is `Wrapper<i32>` and `c` is `Wrapper<i32>`:

```rust
let a = 12i32;
let b = a.to_wrap();
let c = b.to_wrap();
```

I want `v.to_wrap()` to always produce a `Wrapper<T>` where T is **NOT** a `Wrapper`. If `v` is a `Wrapper<T>`, `v.to_wrap()` will also be a `Wrapper<T>` with the same value.

The code I wrote closest to my idea is:

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Wrapper<T>(T);

trait ToWrapper<W> {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> W;
}

impl<T> ToWrapper<Wrapper<T>> for T {
    default fn to_wrap(self) -> Wrapper<T> {
        Wrapper(self)
    }
}

impl<T> ToWrapper<Wrapper<T>> for Wrapper<T> {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> Self {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 1i32;
    println!("{:?}", a);
    let a = 1.to_wrap();
    println!("{:?}", a);
    let a: Wrapper<i32> = 1.to_wrap().to_wrap();
    // let a = 1.to_wrap().to_wrap();
    // boom with `cannot infer type`
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c60f4637fbdee599b1542ad164d3c5b8)

This has a compilation error if I erase the type annotation on from `let a: Wrapper<i32> = 1.to_wrap().to_wrap()`:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:27:9
   |
27 |     let a = 1.to_wrap().to_wrap();
   |         ^
   |         |
   |         cannot infer type
   |         consider giving `a` a type
```

I want the Rust compiler to automatically derive the type of `1.to_wrap().to_wrap()`. How can I write the correct version, or why is it not possible to write it?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe you can accomplish your goal of implementing a single trait using specialization at this point in time.

Your trait definition allows for multiple implementations of the trait for the same type:

```
trait ToWrapper<W> {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> W;
}

impl ToWrapper<i32> for u8 {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> i32 {
        i32::from(self)
    }
}

impl ToWrapper<i16> for u8 {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> i16 {
        i16::from(self)
    }
}
```

With such a setup, it's impossible to know what the resulting type of `to_wrap` *should* be; you will always need to provide the output type somehow. Then you compound the problems by attempting to call `to_wrap` on an unknown type that will produce another unknown type!

Normally, using associated types would be the solution, but you cannot switch to those here because of how they interact with specialization.

See also:

- [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/155423)
- [Mismatch between associated type and type parameter only when impl is marked `default`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51022636/155423)
- [How do I unwrap an arbitrary number of nested Option types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52453180/155423)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried using associated type and as you say it can't complie although I annotate the type.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something like this on nightly, not using specialization, but using two different traits and an auto trait to distinguish between them.

```
#![feature(auto_traits)]
#![feature(negative_impls)]

auto trait IsWrap {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Wrapper<T>(T);

impl<T> !IsWrap for Wrapper<T> {}

trait ToWrapper: Sized {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> Wrapper<Self>;
}

impl<T: IsWrap> ToWrapper for T {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> Wrapper<T> {
        Wrapper(self)
    }
}

trait ToWrapperSelf {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> Self;
}

impl<T> ToWrapperSelf for Wrapper<T> {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> Self {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 1.to_wrap();
    println!("{:?}", a);
    let a = 1.to_wrap().to_wrap(); 
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

As with [chabapok's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55460987/3650362), you can't use this technique to write a generic function that behaves one way when given one type and another way with another type (although see the links below). But you can use it when the concrete type is known to the compiler but not to the programmer -- macros come to mind as a possible use case.

It has one further advantage in that there is no possible ambiguity over which `to_wrap` method will be called on any type. Every type has at most one `to_wrap` method, since `Wrapper`s only have `ToWrapperSelf::is_wrap` and non-`Wrapper`s only have `ToWrapper::is_wrap`.

One other *dis*advantage is that `!IsWrap` for `Wrapper<T>` is "infectious": any type that contains or might contain a `Wrapper<T>` will *also* be automatically `!IsWrap`. If you call `.to_wrap()` on such a type, the compiler will not be able to find the method and will issue an error. If this is a problem, you can manually implement `IsWrap` for these types, but it might be more prudent to look for another, less fragile solution.

(The only exception to the above is `Box<Wrapper<T>>`: you can call `ToWrapperSelf::to_wrap` on it to get a `Wrapper<T>`. This happens due to the autodereferencing rules and because [`Box` is special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264041/how-do-i-get-an-owned-value-out-of-a-box).)

### See also

- [What is an auto trait in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710852/what-is-an-auto-trait-in-rust)
- The solution outlined above is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52453259/3650362).
- [Can I avoid eager ambiguity resolution for trait implementations with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281091/can-i-avoid-eager-ambiguity-resolution-for-trait-implementations-with-generics) has a similar "specialization but not really" flavor. My answer to that question can be combined with this answer to create traits and generic functions that dispatch `Wrapper`s and non-`Wrapper`s transparently, even though you can't leverage the full power of specialization.

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that it'll treat any structure containing `Wrapper` (e.g. `Rc<Wrapper<T>>`) as `Wrapper`, which might be undesirable.

Comment: Thanks. Auto-trait is a new thing to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Wrapper<T>(T);

trait ToWrapper<W> {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> Wrapper<W>;
}

impl<T> ToWrapper<T> for T {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> Wrapper<T> {
        Wrapper(self)
    }
}

impl<T> Wrapper<T> {
    fn to_wrap(self) -> Wrapper<T> {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 1i32;
    println!("{:?}", a);
    let a = 1.to_wrap();
    println!("{:?}", a);
    let a: Wrapper<i32> = 1.to_wrap().to_wrap();
    let b = 1.to_wrap().to_wrap();
    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

Comment: Please use some words to explain how your solution works, as well as identifying any weaknesses it might have.

Comment: Thank. I found there would be unexpected behavior when defining a generic function like `fn foo<T>(value:ToWrapper<T>);`; When I give a `value:Wrapper<T>` to it, it  would use `<Wrapper<T> as ToWrapper<Wrapper<T>>>::to_wrap` rather than `Wrapper<T>::to_wrap`.