# Initialize a Vec with not-None values only

Tags: rust

If I have variables like this:

```
let a: u32 = ...;
let b: Option<u32> = ...;
let c: u32 = ...;
```

, what is the shortest way to make a vector of those values, so that b is only included if it's `Some`?

In other words, is there something simpler than this:

```
let v = match b {
    None => vec![a, c],
    Some(x) => vec![a, x, c],
};
```

P.S. I would prefer a solution where we don't need to use the variables more than once. Consider this example:

```
let some_person: String = ...;
let best_man: Option<String> = ...;
let a_third_person: &str = ...; 
let another_opt: Option<String> = ...;
...
```

As can be seen, we might have to use longer variable names, more than one `Option` (`None`), expressions (like `a_third_person.to_string()`), etc.

Comment: I would probably do a match.

Comment: Do you want a https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ or the most readable answer? Because `match` is definitely the most readable.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I am interested in a concise and readable solution. Keep in mind my example is artificial. In real life we would rather have longer variable names or even expressions.

Comment: well please show a code example that actually **show** the problem so.

Comment: after reading the variables names thing, I don't think there is actually a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yours is fine, but here's a sophisticated one:

```rust
[Some(a), b, Some(c)].into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

This works since [`Option` impls `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-IntoIterator).

Comment: I wonder if bench are same

Comment: [meh](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MxPajdoEz), I would not advice it

Comment: @Stargateur Neither would I :P But it's shorter (if I include whitespaces).

Comment: I was thinking about something similar. I was hoping for something simpler though. The big advantage of this solution is that we only use `a`, `b` and `c` once. In reality, those variables would be longer or we would have expressions, so repeating them would be even worse (and more error prone), in my view. Also, they could be a lot more than 3.

Comment: If there are many optionals, then this method may be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

If it depends on just one variable:

```rust
b.map(|b| vec![a, b, c]).unwrap_or_else(|| vec![a, c]);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45cfddf40aa005841070758c5083aecf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks OK with my example with short variable names. However, in practice we would often have longer variable names or even expressions instead.

Answer (score 2):

After some thinking and investigating, I've come with the following crazy thing.

---

The end goal is to have a macro, `optional_vec![]`, that you can pass it either `T` or `Option<T>` and it should behave like described in the question. However, I decided on a strong restriction: it should have the best performance possible. So, you write:

```rust
optional_vec![a, b, c]
```

And get at least the performance of hand-written `match`, if not more. This forbids the use of the simple `[Some(a), b, Some(c)].into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<_>>()`, suggested in my other answer (though even this solution needs some way to differentiate between `Option<T>` and just `T`, which, like we'll see, is not an easy problem at all).

I will first warn that I've not found a way to make my macro work with `Option`. That is, if you want to build a vector of `Option<T>` from `Option<T>` and `Option<Option<T>>`, it will not work.

---

When a design a complex macro, I like to think first how **the expanded code** will look like. And in this macro, we have several hard problems to solve.

First, the macro take plain expressions. But somehow, it needs to switch on their type being `T` or `Option<T>`. How should such thing be done?

The feature we use to do such things is *specialization*.

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

pub trait Optional {
    fn some_method(self);
}

impl<T> Optional for T {
    default fn some_method(self) {
        // Just T
    }
}

impl<T> Optional for Option<T> {
    fn some_method(self) {
        // Option<T>
    }
}
```

Like you probably noticed, now we have *two* problems: first, specialization is unstable, and I'd like to stay with stable. Second, what should be inside the trait? The second problem is easier to solve, so let's begin with it.

Turns out that the most performant way to do the pushing to the vector is to pre-allocate capacity ([`Vec::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity)), write to the vector by using pointers (don't `push()`, it optimizes badly!) then set the length ([`Vec::set_len()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.set_len)).

We can get a pointer to the internal buffer of the vector using [`Vec::as_mut_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_mut_ptr), and advance the pointer via [`<*mut T>::add(1)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.add-1).

So, we need two methods: one to hint us about the capacity (can be zero for `None` or one for `Some()` and non-`Option` elements), and a `write_and_advance()` method:

```rust
pub trait Optional {
    type Item;
    fn len(&self) -> usize;
    unsafe fn write_and_advance(self, place: &mut *mut Self::Item);
}

impl<T> Optional for T {
    default type Item = Self;
    default fn len(&self) -> usize { 1 }
    default unsafe fn write_and_advance(self, place: &mut *mut Self) {
        place.write(self);
        *place = place.add(1);
    }
}

impl<T> Optional<T> for Option<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn len(&self) -> usize { self.is_some() as usize }
    unsafe fn write_and_advance(self, place: &mut *mut T) {
        if let Some(value) = self {
            place.write(value);
            *place = place.add(1);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't even compile! For the why, see [Mismatch between associated type and type parameter only when impl is marked `default`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022636/mismatch-between-associated-type-and-type-parameter-only-when-impl-is-marked-de). Luckily for us, the trick we'll use to workaround specialization not being stable does work in this situation. But for now, let's assume it works. How will the code using this trait look like?

```rust
match (a, b, c) { // The match is here because it's the best binding for liftimes: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54855986/7884305
    (a, b, c) => {
        let len = Optional::len(&a) + Optional::len(&b) + Optional::len(&c);
        let mut result = ::std::vec::Vec::with_capacity(len);
        
        let mut next_element = result.as_mut_ptr();
        unsafe {
            Optional::write_and_advance(a, &mut next_element);
            Optional::write_and_advance(b, &mut next_element);
            Optional::write_and_advance(c, &mut next_element);
            
            result.set_len(len);
        }
        
        result
    }
}
```

And it works! Except that it does not, because the specialization does not compile as I said, and we also want to *not* repeat all of this boilerplate but insert it into a macro.

So, how do we solve the problems with specialization: being unstable and not working?

dtonlay has a very cool trick he calls [autoref specialization](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/blob/master/autoref-specialization/README.md) (BTW, all of this repo is a very recommended reading!). This is a trick that can be used to emulate specialization. It works only in macros, but we're in a macro so this is fine.

I will not elaborate about the trick here (I recommend to read his post; he also used this trick in the excellent and very widely used [anyhow](https://lib.rs/crates/anyhow) crate). In short, the idea is to trick the typechecker by implementing a trait for `T` under certain conditions (the specialized impl) and other trait for `&T` for the general case (this could be inherent impl if not coherence). Since Rust performs automatic referencing during method resolution, that is take reference to the receiver as needed, this will work - the typechecker will autoref if needed, and will stop in the first applicable impl - i.e. the specialized impl if it matches, or the general impl otherwise.

Here's an example:

```rust
use std::fmt;

pub trait Display {
    fn foo(&self);
}
// Level 1
impl<T: fmt::Display> Display for T {
    fn foo(&self) { println!("Display({}), {}", std::any::type_name::<T>(), self); }
}

pub trait Debug {
    fn foo(&self);
}
// Level 2
impl<T: fmt::Debug> Debug for &T {
    fn foo(&self) { println!("Debug({}), {:?}", std::any::type_name::<T>(), self); }
}

macro_rules! foo {
    ($e:expr) => ((&$e).foo());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=39d84e5c7df2810fa8aebe13a96497e5).

We can use this trick in our case:

```rust
#[doc(hidden)]
pub mod autoref_specialization {
    #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
    pub struct OptionTag;
    pub trait OptionKind {
        fn optional_kind(&self) -> OptionTag; 
    }
    impl<T> OptionKind for Option<T> {
        #[inline(always)]
        fn optional_kind(&self) -> OptionTag { OptionTag }
    }
    impl OptionTag {
        #[inline(always)]
        pub fn len<T>(self, this: &Option<T>) -> usize { this.is_some() as usize }
        #[inline(always)]
        pub unsafe fn write_and_advance<T>(self, this: Option<T>, place: &mut *mut T) {
            if let Some(value) = this {
                place.write(value);
                *place = place.add(1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
    pub struct DefaultTag;
    pub trait DefaultKind {
        fn optional_kind(&self) -> DefaultTag; 
    }
    impl<T> DefaultKind for &'_ T {
        #[inline(always)]
        fn optional_kind(&self) -> DefaultTag { DefaultTag }
    }
    impl DefaultTag {
        #[inline(always)]
        pub fn len<T>(self, _this: &T) -> usize { 1 }
        #[inline(always)]
        pub unsafe fn write_and_advance<T>(self, this: T, place: &mut *mut T) {
            place.write(this);
            *place = place.add(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And the expanded code will look like:

```rust
use autoref_specialization::{DefaultKind as _, OptionKind as _};
match (a, b, c) {
    (a, b, c) => {
        let (a_tag, b_tag, c_tag) = (
            (&a).optional_kind(),
            (&b).optional_kind(),
            (&c).optional_kind(),
        );
        
        let len = a_tag.len(&a) + b_tag.len(&b) + c_tag.len(&c);
        let mut result = ::std::vec::Vec::with_capacity(len);
        
        let mut next_element = result.as_mut_ptr();
        unsafe {
            a_tag.write_and_advance(a, &mut next_element);
            b_tag.write_and_advance(b, &mut next_element);
            c_tag.write_and_advance(c, &mut next_element);
            
            result.set_len(len);
        }
        
        result
    }
}
```

It may be tempting to try to convert this immediately into a macro, but we still have one unsolved problem: our macro need to generate identifiers. This may not be obvious, but what if we pass `optional_vec![1, Some(2), 3]`? We need to generate the bindings for the `match` (in our case, `(a, b, c) => ...`) and the tag names (`(a_tag, b_tag, c_tag)`).

Unfortunately, generating names is not something `macro_rules!` can do in today's Rust. Fortunately, there is an excellent crate [paste](https://lib.rs/crates/paste) (another one from dtonlay!) that is a small proc-macro that allows you to do that. It is even available on the playground!

However, we need a series of identifiers. That can be done with tt-munching, by repeatedly adding some letter (I used `a`), so you get `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, ... you get the idea.

```rust
#[doc(hidden)]
pub mod reexports {
    pub use std::vec::Vec;
    
    pub use paste::paste;
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! optional_vec {
    // Empty case
    { @generate_idents
        exprs = []
        processed_exprs = [$($e:expr,)*]
        match_bindings = [$($binding:ident)*]
        tags = [$($tag:ident)*]
    } => {{
        use $crate::autoref_specialization::{DefaultKind as _, OptionKind as _};
        match ($($e,)*) {
            ($($binding,)*) => {
                let ($($tag,)*) = (
                    $((&$binding).optional_kind(),)*
                );
                
                let len = 0 $(+ $tag.len(&$binding))*;
                let mut result = $crate::reexports::Vec::with_capacity(len);
                
                let mut next_element = result.as_mut_ptr();
                unsafe {
                    $($tag.write_and_advance($binding, &mut next_element);)*
                    
                    result.set_len(len);
                }
                
                result
            }
        }
    }};
    
    { @generate_idents
        exprs = [$e:expr, $($rest:expr,)*]
        processed_exprs = [$($processed_exprs:tt)*]
        match_bindings = [$first_binding:ident $($bindings:ident)*]
        tags = [$($tags:ident)*]
    } => {
        $crate::reexports::paste! {
            $crate::optional_vec! { @generate_idents
                exprs = [$($rest,)*]
                processed_exprs = [$($processed_exprs)* $e,]
                match_bindings = [
                    [< $first_binding a >]
                    $first_binding
                    $($bindings)*
                ]
                tags = [
                    [< $first_binding a_tag >]
                    $($tags)*
                ]
            }
        }
    };
    
    // Entry
    [$e:expr $(, $exprs:expr)* $(,)?] => {
        $crate::optional_vec! { @generate_idents
            exprs = [$($exprs,)+]
            processed_exprs = [$e,]
            match_bindings = [__optional_vec_a]
            tags = [__optional_vec_a_tag]
        }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a9a895c02c46061e61a584cd00c50cc).

Answer (score 2):

I can also personally recommend

```rust
let mut v = vec![a, c];
v.extend(b);
```

Short and clear.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice solution, when the order of elements is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime the straight forward solution is the best:

```rust
fn jim_power(a: u32, b: Option<u32>, c: u32) -> Vec<u32> {
   let mut acc = Vec::with_capacity(3);
   acc.push(a);
   if let Some(b) = b {
       acc.push(b);
   }
   acc.push(c);
   acc
}

fn ys_iii(
    some_person: String,
    best_man: Option<String>,
    a_third_person: String,
    another_opt: Option<String>,
) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut acc = Vec::with_capacity(4);
    acc.push(some_person);
    best_man.map(|x| acc.push(x));
    acc.push(a_third_person);
    another_opt.map(|x| acc.push(x));
    acc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order of the values, another option is

```
Iterator::chain(
    [a, c].into_iter(),
    [b].into_iter().flatten()
).collect()
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2b80a0aa94006fe583e9284c82ad123)

Comment: better `b.into_iter().flatten()`, no need to allocate the array there

Comment: @Netwave Array allocation is zero cost, but better is `b.into_iter()` (no `.flatten()`, it will not work anyway) just because it's simpler.

Comment: @ChayimFriedmam I opted for an array since OP indicated that in their real code there are more than just 3 expressions and my version is easier to extend to that situation.